# Task based behavior is blocking the parent thread

Tags: c#

Assuming that I need to have some concurrent processes and I would like to forget about the old `Thread` class and stick to `Task` with an async pattern. Given the following codes:

```
// Scenario 1
public async Task Accept() {
    while(true) {
        Connection con = await connection.AcceptAsync();
        await HandleConnection(con);
    }
}

public Task HandleConnection(Connection con) {

   // Long Running Logic
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}

// Scenario 2
public async Task Accept() {
    while(true) {
        Connection con = await connection.AcceptAsync();
        HandleConnection(con); // Produces a warning
    }
}

public Task HandleConnection(Connection con) {

   // Long Running Logic
   return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Both these approaches fail and I cannot handle the connection concurrently. For example when the first connection is accepted then I cannot accept the second connection until the `HandleConnection` method finishes its job. To solve this problem I can do the following:

```
public async Task Accept() {
    while(true) {
        Connection con = await connection.AcceptAsync();
        HandleConnection(con); // Produces a warning
    }
}

public Task HandleConnection(Connection con) {
    return Task.Run(()=> {
        //Long Running Logic
    });
}
```

Now I am able to handle multiple connections but this behavior raises a few questions:

1- I heard that the `await` keyword in contrast with `wait` is non-blocking and in fact the whole async pattern in non-blocking as well. But in this situation it is actually blocking the parent thread.

2- When a method is async, a Task resembling that method must be generated as a result so that it can be awaited, is that true? if that is true then why is it blocking? else how does the await mechanism work?

3- If I don't await the Task, I get a compile time warning which says I have to await the task, but if I use it then the parent thread is blocked.

To ditch the warning I can do `HandleConnection(con).Wait(0)` but isn't that a bad practice?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I played with this issue and tested that thoroughly. The conclusion is that in a method that returns a Task, if you do not actually return a Task or instead await or return `Task.CompletedTask`, that method will still run on the Parent thread and will surely block it. You can only benefit from multithreading if you actually raise a Task as I represented in my question.

To prove this, the following is blocking:

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    test();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
private static Task test() {
    while(true) {}
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In this code `test` will block the main thread.

If you make the `test` async, it will still block the main thread.

```
public static void Main(String[] args) {
    test();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
private static async Task test() {
    while(true) {}
}
```

This is while the following does not block the main thread:

```
public static async Task test() {
        await Task.Run(()=> {
            while(true) {}
        });
    }
```

However, if you don't want to await the Task you should raise the Task in void method:

```
public void Method() {
     Task.Run(()=> ());
}
```

This is much better than `Task.Wait(0)`.

Comment: 1) Use `await Task.Yield();` to force an async method to actually be async. 2) Your "non-blocking" `test()` _is_ blocking! Tasks are designed to be _awaited_, and your `test()` never completes. Anyone who awaits it will be blocked forever. You must not design tasks that never complete, and that is fundamentally the source of your problems: you are shooting yourself in the foot by awaiting a task in the middle of your program that will never complete.

Comment: @Jeff: That is absolutely right and I agree, I just wanna demonstrate what actually happens.

Comment: @Jeff: However, `Use await Task.Yield(); to force an async method to actually be async` is not right. You just keep the method signature using that.